# Нужна ли точка после вопросительного знака и кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли точка после вопросительного знака и кавычек в данном случае.
*«В магазине скоро начнется распродажа. На какие именно товары и в какое время?». На вопросы по просьбе покупателей ответил продавец-консультант…*

Comment: Пример надо курсивом оформить и с новой строки. А то каша, непонятно, где пример начинается.

Comment: Нужен контекст. Непонятно, кто говорит то, что в кавычках. Похоже на диалог.